# Programmatically close multiple jQuery Mobile dialogs at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following in jQuery mobile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#locate_results").live("pageinit", function(event) {
        $("#venues li a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Update location
            $(".ui-dialog").each(function() { $(this).dialog("close"); });
        });
    });
</script>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">My Form</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        ... other content ...
        <a href="#locator" data-rel="dialog">Choose a Location</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="dialog" id="locator">
    <div data-role="header">Search for a Location</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="/locate" method="post" data-rel="dialog">
            <input type="text" name="query" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output of /locate is as follows:

```
<div id="locate_results" data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header">Search Results</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="venues" data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">Venue 1 Name</a></li>
            ... more results ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So essentially,

1. User clicks the "Add a Location" link.
2. Location search form is loaded in a dialog
3. Search results loaded in a second dialog
4. User clicks a search result in the second dialog.

Step 5 should be both dialogs closing, returning the user to the original page content. However only the topmost dialog (#locate_results) closes. I have also tried the following and gotten the same result:

```
$("#locate_results").dialog("close");
$("#locator").dialog("close");
```

and

```
$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");
```

I've tried following these answers, with no luck:

- [close multiple jquery ui dialogs at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742277/close-multiple-jquery-ui-dialogs-at-once)

What would be the correct way to close all open dialogs in jQuery Mobile?

jsFiddle demonstrating the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/zUuSy/

Comment: Posting a jsFiddle would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug.

Here's a snip from jQuery Mobile's close method:

```
// Close method goes back in history
close: function() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

What's happening is certain browsers run into issues with calling `window.history.back()` multiple times in succession, so calling `$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close")` only goes back in history once. However, calling `window.history.go(-2)` appears to work.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/rummik/zUuSy/4/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Mobile's docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html) are pretty explicit:

> You can also call the dialog's `close()` method to programmatically
>   close dialogs, for example: `$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close')`.

Are you using the correct selector at the correct time? It should be working.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm confused. I'm using the exact selectors you see above, while both dialogs are active.

Comment: @TomH I tried replicating this in jsFiddle but the form threw me for a loop. Can you try posting one, and I'll try to come back and amend my answer?

Comment: Also, I know the click event is firing because the code replaced with the comment "Update location" is firing, and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: I updated the original post with a link to the jsFiddle. Thanks for your help.